# Can't find variable: Symbol from <unknown> (on Physical React Native Android device only)

Tags: android, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

Running the newest version of RN, I get the below error. It only occurs however on a physical Android device (tried two different ones) - Android simulators and iOS are fine.

Any ideas on whether this is some kind of caching issue (which I doubt based on all my clearing techniques) or a code error?

I have tried following advice on questions that are reasonably similar to this, but no luck.

*Worth noting that I have mobx installed which has caused this error message before, although it has always shown to come from there rather than showing unknown in the error's description.*

Many thanks!

**In Android Studio I get this error (unsure if the two are related):**

> E/ReactNativeJS: Can't find variable: Symbol
>   E/ReactNativeJS: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

**React Native Error Screenshot:**

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: i think this looks like import export issue in your code.

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAshfaq - many thanks for the comment. Could you elaborate please? Unsure what you mean by import export.

Comment: i usually got this error when i forgot to import StyleSheet but using it in my app. Can you please tell me that is there any component you have with  name of Symbol ?

Comment: Ah interesting @MuhammadAshfaq, thanks for sharing. Have checked and nope, no component named Symbol is called from my code.

Comment: Can you please share `react-native` and `mobx` version?

Comment: Sure thing @RaviRupareliya: "react-native": "0.58.3", "mobx": "^5.9.0" ... and these are also likely relevant... "jsc-android": "236355.1.1",  "mobx-react": "^5.4.3", "mobx-state-tree": "^3.10.2"

Comment: I've got this exact same problem, after adding `mobx` and then trying to remove the warnings about the use of `@observer`

Comment: Super interesting @diogenesgg - which warnings are those? Cheers

Comment: @hardanger see this https://imgur.com/a/VZi0JCj

Comment: The truth is: "Warning: since upgrading JSC is non-trivial, and decorators can be troublesome as well in React Native, for now it is recommended to stick to MobX 4.x for for React Native Android development."
From https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx#browser-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having trouble setting up `mobx` and `mobx-react` on my project, created using `react-native init`. 
I was having this very similar problem when running on my physical device, an Android Samsung J7 Pro.

**At the end, it was about not installing `mobx` properly.**

At first, I was getting the following black screen error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExSlC.png

Then after 1~2 seconds, this screen would turn to the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D74Ia.png

MobX >=5 is not supposed to run straight forward on React Native Android.
Then I just had to make sure to follow these steps to get it running:

- 1. `brew install coreutils`
- 2. `npm install jsc-android --save`
- 3. Follow [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#how-to-use-it-with-my-react-native-app) instructions (on Android Studio)
- 4. Follow [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#troubleshooting) troubleshooting. (on Android Studio). For me, it was complaining about a file called `libjsc.so`.
- 5. `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`
- 6. change my babel.config.js file to the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]
  ]
}
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mobx_testing",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsc-android": "^236355.1.1",
    "mobx": "^5.9.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer @diogenesgg. Before you sent this I decided to rebuild the app without MobX which resolved the issue, but from what I could see it looked very much like MobX wasn't quite installed right and your solution looks likely to fix what I had. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, `.yarnclean` makes error in my case.

If you have `.yarnclean` file, remove `assets` line or remove the file.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Gui Kang, but sadly I don't have that file (I guess as I'm not using Yarn, just NPM)